# styling nested unordered list into columns

Tags: html, css

I want to have a nested list to appear as a group of columns.

Each level of the list should be a new column, and all the columns should be aligned to the top. Something like this:

[image: nested list as a table]

Displaying submenus or not is easy enough, but I can't get the positioning to work without some weird negative top or something like that.

Is there some logical and neat way to achive this?

I have the beginning of the code [here in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yivi/rawun4bw/)

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Top 1
            <ul>
                <li>Sub 1.1</li>
                <li>Sub 1.2</li>
                <li>Sub 1.3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='current-item'>Top 2
            <ul>
                <li>Sub 2.1</li>
                <li class="current-item">Sub 2.2
                    <ul>
                        <li>Bottom 2.2.1</li>
                        <li>Bottom 2.2.2</li>
                        <li>Bottom 2.2.3</li>
                        <li class="current-item">Bottom 2.2.4</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Sub 2.3</li>
                <li>Sub 2.4</li>
                <li>Sub 2.5</li>
                <li>Sub 2.6</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Top 3
            <ul>
                <li>Sub 3.1</li>
                <li>Sub 3.2</li>
                <li>Sub 3.3</li>
                <li>Sub 3.4</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And a skeleton scss:

```
#menu {
/* top level */
ul {
    border: 1px solid black;
    list-style: none;
    li 
        /* sub level */
        ul {
            display: none;
            li {
                /* bottom of the pit */
                ul {
                    li {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

#menu .current-item > ul{
    display: block;
}
```

Any takers?

Comment: Also i make a try here http://jsfiddle.net/rawun4bw/2/

Comment: closer, but it doesn't really work... :\ Thx anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about positioning the submenu's by reference to the parent `ul` rather than, as is traditional, the `li`

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rawun4bw/4/)

**Added CSS**

```
#menu > ul {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
#menu >ul > li ul {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:100%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something like this as well but somehow Paulie_D's example didn't work for me (alignment of columns didn't look right). I fiddled around myself and came up with the following possible solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/lumpie/jrrp1hy2/

```
#menu {
  width: 100%;
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  li {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .current-item {
    color: red;
    > ul {
      display: block;
    }
  }
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  > ul ul {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
  }
  > ul {
    position: relative;
    width: 20%; // = 5 columns
  }
}
```